# How to display a poll result using react native

Tags: react-native

I would appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction to create a poll result such like Zoom.

[Find a sample below and would appreciate it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5dWC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this repo : [react-native-polls-api-example](https://github.com/aarkalyk/react-native-polls-api-example)

You can duplicate this project and test it on your side, there is a great documentation [here](https://pollsapi.docs.apiary.io/)

Comment: Thanks. This project was helpful and also seeing how you used LinearGradient here